# drop_duplicates() in Pandas Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas

Having below data set:

```
A,B,C,D
1,A_Task,WID,WI_DTL
1,A_adhoc_load,ATT,IXN_1
1,A_adhoc_load,ATT,IXN_10
1,A_adhoc_load,ATT,IXN_100
1,A_adhoc_load,ATT,IXN_101
2,Batch_Support,ATT,CDS_STATUS
2,Batch_Support,ATT,CDS_CONTROL
2,Batch_Support,ATT,CDS_ORA_STATUS
2,Batch_Support,ATT,REP_FILTER
1,online_load,ATT,TAX_3
1,online_load,ATT,TAX_4
1,online_load,ATT,TAX_8
1,online_load,ATT,TAX_11
```

Want the Output as below:

```
A,B,C,D
1,A_Task,WID,WI_DTL
1,A_adhoc_load,ATT,IXN
2,Batch_Support,ATT,CDS_STATUS
2,Batch_Support,ATT,CDS_CONTROL
2,Batch_Support,ATT,CDS_ORA_STATUS
2,Batch_Support,ATT,REP_FILTER
1,online_load,ATT,TAX
```

i.e. want to remove element in "D", where duplicate is in the form of %_[0-9]+

## Had performed the below steps:

```
import pandas as pd


cs = pd.read_csv('inp.csv')

cs["NEW"] = cs.D.str.match('([A-Z]+)\_[0-9]+')
print cs


    A                B    C               D      NEW
0   1       Adhoc_Task  WID          WI_DTL      []  
1   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT           IXN_1  (IXN,)
2   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT          IXN_10  (IXN,)
3   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT         IXN_100  (IXN,)
4   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT         IXN_101  (IXN,)
5   2    Batch_Support  ATT      CDS_STATUS      []
6   2    Batch_Support  ATT     CDS_CONTROL      []
7   2    Batch_Support  ATT  CDS_ORA_STATUS      []
8   2    Batch_Support  ATT      REP_FILTER      []
9   1      online_load  ATT           TAX_3  (TAX,)
10  1      online_load  ATT           TAX_4  (TAX,)
11  1      online_load  ATT           TAX_8  (TAX,)
12  1      online_load  ATT          TAX_11  (TAX,)


cs_new=cs[cs.NEW != []]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 572, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 533, in na_op
    result = lib.vec_compare(x, y, op)
  File "lib.pyx", line 671, in pandas.lib.vec_compare (pandas/lib.c:12404)
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 13 vs 0

cs_new=cs[cs.NEW == []]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 572, in wrapper
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 572, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 533, in na_op
    result = lib.vec_compare(x, y, op)
  File "lib.pyx", line 671, in pandas.lib.vec_compare (pandas/lib.c:12404)
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 13 vs 0


cs.drop_duplicates('NEW')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 60, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2590, in drop_duplicates

duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, take_last=take_last)
File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 60, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2639, in duplicated
duplicated = lib.duplicated(keys, take_last=take_last)
File "lib.pyx", line 1202, in pandas.lib.duplicated (pandas/lib.c:20180)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

My Idea was to:

```
1. Split based on value of D. 1st DF having D==[] and 2nd DF having D!=[]
2. Remove duplicate using col "NEW".
3. Append the DFs.
4. Then Drop column "New" to obtain the final result.
```

I also tried below:

```
cs['NEW'].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1128, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(take_last=take_last)
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1149, in duplicated
    duplicated = lib.duplicated(keys, take_last=take_last)
  File "lib.pyx", line 1202, in pandas.lib.duplicated (pandas/lib.c:20180)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

list(set(cs['NEW']))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Please help out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str.replace` to remove the ending numeric part for the strings in `D`:

```
In [204]: df['D'] = df['D'].str.replace(r'_[0-9]+$', '')

In [205]: df
Out[205]: 
    A              B    C               D
0   1         A_Task  WID          WI_DTL
1   1   A_adhoc_load  ATT             IXN
2   1   A_adhoc_load  ATT             IXN
3   1   A_adhoc_load  ATT             IXN
4   1   A_adhoc_load  ATT             IXN
5   2  Batch_Support  ATT      CDS_STATUS
6   2  Batch_Support  ATT     CDS_CONTROL
7   2  Batch_Support  ATT  CDS_ORA_STATUS
8   2  Batch_Support  ATT      REP_FILTER
9   1    online_load  ATT             TAX
10  1    online_load  ATT             TAX
11  1    online_load  ATT             TAX
12  1    online_load  ATT             TAX
```

Then use `groupby/first`:

```
In [216]: df.groupby('D', as_index=False, sort=False).first()[list('ABCD')]
Out[216]: 
   A              B    C               D
0  1         A_Task  WID          WI_DTL
1  1   A_adhoc_load  ATT             IXN
2  2  Batch_Support  ATT      CDS_STATUS
3  2  Batch_Support  ATT     CDS_CONTROL
4  2  Batch_Support  ATT  CDS_ORA_STATUS
5  2  Batch_Support  ATT      REP_FILTER
6  1    online_load  ATT             TAX
```

Comment: Want to remove 0,1,2 at beginning of line. How it can be done

Comment: The 0,1,2,etc. are the index values. Every DataFrame has an index.  If you want to get rid of them for the purpose of presentation, you could use `print(df.to_csv(None, index=False))`.

Comment: Used df1.to_csv('output.csv', index=False) to write to o/p CSV.